# Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall application

Tags: windows-8, installation, sql-server

I am running Windows 8, 64 bit and have SQL Server 2012 installed.  I downloaded the client tools, looked in the directory for SQL Server Management Studio, and see it's there.  When I try to run SQL Management Studio I receive the error message:

> "Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall application".

This problem just started. I have reinstalled the application and downloaded the service packs. The shortcut key shows the path but it still will not run.

Comment: Are you trying to install something?  If so what?  When do you get the error message?  What OS are you running? Please explain in detail exactly what is happening.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to answer this question, since you haven't told us what application or OS.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you uninstalled Visual Studio 2010? Try installing the isolated package: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366)

Comment: Could you please mind to add more details in you answer?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath, Some features of SQL Server Management Studio requires of MS Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This was exaly what was missing - thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when trying to open SQL Server Mgt Studio 2012 until I followed [this recommended fix by Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690773/after-installing-visual-studio-11-my-sql-server-denali-cannot-be-opened):

> Posted by Microsoft on 10/25/2011 at 6:01 PM
>
> This happens after
>   installing SQL Server 2012 (Code named "Denali CTP3") or later,
>   running SSMS successfully, then (later) install VS11 Dev Preview, and
>   then run SSMS.
>
> Dev11 Preview improperly recognize SQL Server Denali SSMS as a version
>   11 application and it updates the current user’s setting in SSMS
>   registry key during the setup. This issue occurs only when Dev11
>   Preview is installed after the installation of SSMS.
>
> SQL Server 2012 SSMS has a built-in security and resiliency feature
>   for any corrupted configuration in HKCU registry key. The corrupted
>   registry keys can be simply deleted then SSMS automatically
>   reconstructs it with correct values during the next startup procedure.
>
> • Start regedit.exe
>
> • Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
>   Studio
>
> • Delete 11.0_Config
>
> • Restart ssms.exe

Comment: Same goes for 2014, I had 12.0 and 12.0_config in my registry. After several reinstalls, complete cleans, repairs and other shenanigans the web directed me too this 1 minute solution let's me finally start SSMS 2014 again.

Comment: and for Microsoft SQL server 2016, the folder is 14.0_Config.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today.  Probably because I had uninstalled VS2012 and may have accidently uninstalled a VS Shell.

Installing the 2014 SSMS Express Edition Fixed my 2012 SSMS

Answer (score 2):

This finally worked for me: http://klevster.com/fix/sql20122014-management-studio-cannot-find-one-or-more-components-please-reinstall-the-application/

I had to uninstall 2010 shell and then repair MSSMS 2014.

From the link above:

> Struck an issue with a Windows 2012 Server with VS2012 installed trying to open SQL 2012 Management Studio giving the error:
>
> “Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application”
>
> After having tried a heap of combination of things, installing SQL 2014 Management Studio, uninstalling, reinstalling… Then repairing VS2012, installing SQL 2014 Management Studio again. All to no avail.
>
> What finally got me over the line was to uninstall the Visual Studio 2010 Shell, this was done by downloading the installer from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366
>
> Once downloaded, run the installer and remove the VS2010 Shell component. Once done, run the SQL 2014 Management Studio installer or do a repair on your existing installation, this will itself reinstall the VS2010 Shell components.
>
> Then bam, it finally opened for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem seems to be some kind of access issue. I had logged with my domain account during installation, but disconnected from my domain.

Later I repaired the sql server setup while I am connected to the domain, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In cleaning off old installs of SQL Server, I uninstalled the VS2010 shell thinking in wouldn't need it for the latest verison I've been using, which is 2012.

Got the same error. Reinstalled the 2010 shell (~1GB in size) and all is healed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Win2008Server when trying to open SQL Server Mgt Studio 2012 after updating from VS2010 to 2012.
I did the registry thing Ray Vega suggested, rebooted, but no cigar. After this I installed the VSIsoShell.exe. Then the SQL Server Mgt Studio 2012 opened OK.

Here's the link to VSIsoShell.exe:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366

Comment: I feel this would be better as a comment on the Ray Vega answer, rather than a new answer in itself. Flagged as such.